# Merge two bytearray in Action Script

Tags: actionscript-3, video-capture, audio-recording

I'm trying to develop a recorder using action script, and as for now I am able to record the screen and audio into separate-2 file (let's say audio.wav and video.flv ) now I want to merge those two file into a single file.

Is there any way to do this ?

I would be thankful for any kind of suggestions and help.

Comment: I don't really have a solution or answer, but wouldn't just merging two arrays make a total mess? You need to figure out how to add an audio track to your video, merging the byte arrays won't help you there.

Comment: @DodgerThud : I was thinking the same....is there any other way to accomplish this.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760496/encode-video-from-any-format-to-flv-format-in-as3).

Comment: What has ByteArray has to do with those two files you are creating?! If you convert both to byte arrays, you can simply create third one, with a simple separator. Then, in the 'reader' app, you can read the byte array and extract the separator, so you can again have two byte arrays.